# No water pressure after new installation

Tags: water-pressure

We installed a new kitchen faucet and a new shower head and have no water pressure in either.

All the plumbing in the house has been recently installed. We checked all the supply lines and connections. There is pressure in the tub faucet, the bathroom sink faucet. There is pressure in the dishwasher and the kitchen sink sprayer.

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what troubleshooting you've done?  Otherwise the first answer is going to be, "turn the water on"

Comment: Who installed the new plumbing ? A plumber ?

Comment: **Moderator note**: some comments removed because their content is now included in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the sink sprayer has pressure, water is getting to the sink, through the sink valves, and to the redirection valve... so the question would be why it isn't getting to the main tap. Presumably something is blocking/plugging that path. If removing the aerator doesn't solve the problem (in which case you need to replace that aerator), and you're sure the tap has in fact been hooked up (check underneath; some snap-on connection systems may be self-sealing if left unconnected), the only thought I've got would be to disassemble and see if you can find the blockage.

Shower head: Is there also a tub spout, and does it work? What happens when you remove the head again and just try to run water through the pipe? Are you sure you haven't thrown the "stop water while I soap" valve?

Comment: This reminds me of a bunch of work I did.  The plumbing in the bathroom was not used for a few months.  Once everything was finished and I hooked up the faucets, they worked briefly and just slowly lost pressure until they stopped.  I took off the aerator and they were clogged with just sediments from the lines not being used.